# Custom search filter in the react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I have some data presented in List (react-admin component). I can add SearchInput into my Filter component that is used as filter in the List, type source in it and then data will be filtered by full match of the "source" field with text typped into the SearchInput. Is it possible to construct regular expression using text from the input and  filter data based on regular expression, not the full match?

I have already tried dumb way - to change filters manually (i.e. set onChange prop for the SearchInput with my method which do the change) but it resulted in some unwanted side effects.

So the question again is, whether it is possible to filter data in  based on regular expression that is constructed based on user input?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your code before?